# Long SwiftUI list causes visible lag on cell update

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an app with a long list that triggers a server-pull when a cell gets displayed. This server pull will cause the cell to update. Items are stored in a dict and an index list locally, and shown in a lazy v stack. This doesn't seem to me to be the kind of update that should cause a modern iPhone to stutter but it definitely makes the animations less smooth. Seems like I'm doing something obvious wrong but I can't seem to find the issue. I wrote an example app here. The gist is:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TestView()
            .environmentObject(globalState)
            .task {
                (0...10000).forEach { _ in
                    globalState.newItem()
                }
                updateLater()
            }
    }

    func updateLater() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            update()
        }
    }

    func update() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let id = globalState.itemIds[3]
            var item = globalState.itemDict[id]!
            item.newColor()
            item.text = "changed"
            globalState.itemDict[id] = item
        }
        updateLater()
    }
}

extension State {
    func newItem() {
        let item = Item()
        itemDict[item.id] = item
        itemIds.append(item.id)
    }
}

let globalState = State()

struct TestView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var state: State

    var items: [Item] {
        state.itemList.filter {
            !$0.text.isEmpty
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                    row(item)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func row(_ item: Item) -> some View {
        Button {

        } label: {
            Text(item.text)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding()
                .background(item.color.opacity(0.2))
        }
    }
}

class State: ObservableObject {
    @Published var itemIds: [UUID] = []
    @Published var itemDict: [UUID: Item] = [:]

    var itemList: [Item] {
        itemIds.compactMap {
            itemDict[$0]
        }
    }
}

func randomColor() -> Color { Color(hue: .random(in: 0...1), saturation: 0.9, brightness: 0.5) }

struct Item {
    var id = UUID()
    var text = "Hello"
    var color = randomColor()

    mutating func newColor() {
        color = randomColor()
    }
}
```

I feel like there's a swiftui feature I'm missing here. There has to be a better way... my real app is way laggier than the example.

Comment: The task is executing on the main thread because it inherits the actor from where it was called. All the update work seems to be running on the main thread, taking away resources that are impacting scroll actions. I suggest using a detached task and setting to a background priority.

Comment: You are missing "Concurrency" there is a lot going on but you are mixing "Concurrency" and `DispatchQueue` they don't mix. "Concurrency" is meant to replace the older options. There are some other issues that will cause headaches such as all the global stuff but if you focus on Concurrency it will come to light, especially if you enable all the "flags"

Comment: `var items: [ItemModel] {` is likely a huge factor though, computed properties run every time it is accessed.

Comment: @loremipsum how else would you store items so that they can be accessed by ID in constant runtime? they are structs so I cannot just clone them into one dict and one array. the dict should be the one source of truth imo

Comment: Something more static, you are mapping up to 10000 items 10000 times on load and then another 10000 every time swiftui decides to load the body.

Comment: i get your point, but since everything here is O(1) I highly doubt it increases draw time. should take less than 8ms which is 120Hz.

Comment: I did (in my real app) remove the computed properly entirely, and only accessed the dict inside the for each. iterating over the id list instead. the performance was unchanged

Comment: what is interesting to me is what you’ve said about removing the dispatch queues. i need that in my real application to ensure the order of tasks isn’t messed with. is there an alternative that lets me create a task queue or add tasks to a queue somehow? Task { smth() } is executed out of order

Comment: Concurrency, watch Meet Async Await

Comment: I have an outside loop that's coming from a non-concurrent third party library. if I then move the data from that callback into the concurrent context, it loses its order. I've tried global actors, custom actors, nothing makes the tasks that I create in the delegate callback go in the right order. I've finally found a custom async semaphore someone wrote but it seems like a hack

Comment: If you convert to async await it will all work in order, but you have to convert properly watch the video

Comment: i have seen the video. if I have a delegate method that gets called by a library that doesn’t support async await, then all I can do to put those callbacks in order is wrapping them inside Task { } which messes up the order